# Higher direct image of a sheaf on product of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a projective varieties, $\mathcal{F}\in\text{Coh}(X\times Y)$. Is it possible to compute $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ for $i>0$, where $f:X\times Y\to X$ is a projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much more general than what you think.

**Proposition.** Let $S$ be a locally noetherian scheme and $f : X\to S$ be a proper morphism of schemes with fibers of dimension $\leq n$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-Module. Then $R^if_*\mathscr{F}=0$ when $i>n$.

*Proof.* The coherent case is treated in the stacks project [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/coherent.pdf), lemma 18.9. We can suppose that $S$ is affine, as the assertion is local on $S$, in which case he have to show that $H^i (X,\mathscr{F}) = 0$ when $i > 0$. Then simply calculate $H^i (X,\mathscr{F})$ by Čech cohomology, that is, thanks to a Čech complex, by taking $(U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ a finite open affine coverering of $X$. To conclude, we will show that this Čech is exact. Namely, take a $\xi$ the kernel of the arrow $$\mathscr{C}^{i}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F})\to \mathscr{C}^{i+1}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F})$$ and show that it is in the image of the arrow $$\mathscr{C}^{i-1}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F})\to \mathscr{C}^{i}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}).$$ For this, thanks to EGA I, (9.4.7) and (9.4.4) we can show that $\mathscr{F}$ is the inductive limit of its *coherent* sub-$\mathscr{O}_X$-Modules $\mathscr{F}_{\lambda}$. Take $\xi$ in the kernel of $$\mathscr{C}^{i}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F})\to \mathscr{C}^{i+1}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}),$$ as $(U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$ is finite, only finitely many sections are "defining" $\xi$, and by exactness in the coherent case, you know that you can find a $\lambda$ such that $\xi$ is in $$\textrm{Ker}(\mathscr{C}^{i}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}_{\lambda})\to \mathscr{C}^{i+1}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}_{\lambda})) = \textrm{Im}(\mathscr{C}^{i-1}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}_{\lambda})\to \mathscr{C}^{i}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}_{\lambda}))$$ and then $\xi$ is in $$\mathscr{C}^{i-1}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F})\to \mathscr{C}^{i}((U_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}, \mathscr{F}).$$ $\square$

Now, do you see how to apply this proposition to your case ?

Comment: The direct consequence is that $R^if_*=0$ when $i>\text{dim}\,Y$.

Comment: Exactly, yes ;-) Your case is dealt with by the reference in my answer, and in fact it is even more general.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to vote so let me just say that your answer is very useful.

Comment: Thx a lot ;-) I'm note a vote digger, so no problem ! Validating is in fact the principal, so that others know that the "case" is closed. Let me mention that I looked in detail at the stack project reference I gave to you, and it is really perfect to start with to study cohomology (for the Zariski topology) of qc/c-sheaves of O_X modules.